# How to import classes from C++ to Cython that uses function overloading

Tags: python, c++, overloading, cython

I have classes nested in classes and inside of a namespace in c++ in the following format:

```cpp
namespace my_Namespace{
    class MyFirstClass{
       class NestedClass{
          public:
            NestedClass(int arg){};
            NestedClass(double arg{};
            NestedClass(std::string arg){};
       };
    };
};
```

And from the documentation you import the classes in cython like so:

```py
cdef extern from "myfile.hpp" namespace "my_Namespace":
   cdef cppclass MyFirstClass "my_Namespace::MyFirstClass"
   cdef cppclass NestedClass "my_Namespace::MyFirstClass::NestedClass`
```

Side note, do we need any imports for the cython script to use cppclass? Im not seeing it as a keyword.

Anyway, since `NestedClass` has constructor overload how would I implement each in cython? I am trying to do this so that it can be normally imported in python, am I better off just making the whole c++ namespace and functions and putting them in a DLL and just use `ctypes` to import and use the functions?

And one last question I am seeing the documents create classes from the cython code above like so:

```py
cdef class NestedClass:
    cdef NestedClass* obj_
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.obj_=new NestedClass()
    def __dealloc__(self): del self.obj_
```

Is this correct and can I just use the `NestClass` that I got from the C++ file to derive classes like so:

```py
`cdef class NestedClassInt:
   cdef NestedClass* obj_
   def __cinit__(self,arg:int): self.obj_=new NestedClass(arg)
#Now define the define the string one
 def class NestedClassString:
   cdef NestedClass* obj_
   def __cinit__(self,arg:str): self.obj_=new NestedClass(arg)
```

I have been reading multiple forums and I know that python does not support constructor overloading so I don't see if Cython does or if there is a way to convert from it.

Comment: Cython supports declaring multiple constructors for your cppclasses. However it doesn't support multiple constructors for your cdef classes.

Comment: So then how would I go about creating the classes that are dependent on different parameter types?

Comment: staticmethods/classmethods would be one option. A bunch of `isinstance` checks inside `__cinit__` would be another

Comment: Do you have a demonstration I don't follow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upshot as I explained in the comments is that you can declare the overloads for your C++ methods and Cython understands them. You can't declare overloads for methods of cdef classes, and therefore need to pick some other way of switching based on type.

I suggested either using different factory functions (classmethods/staticmethods) or using `isinstance` in `__init__`.

```
# distutils: language = c++

from libcpp.string cimport string as std_string

cdef extern from * namespace "my_Namespace":
    """
    namespace my_Namespace{
    class MyFirstClass{
      public:
       class NestedClass{
          public:
            NestedClass(int arg){};
            NestedClass(double arg){};
            NestedClass(std::string arg){};
       };
    };
    };
    """
    cdef cppclass MyFirstClass:
        cppclass NestedClass:
            NestedClass(int arg)
            NestedClass(double arg)
            NestedClass(std_string arg)

cdef class NestedClassWrapper:
    cdef MyFirstClass.NestedClass* nc
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.nc

    @classmethod  # use staticmethod to make this cdef
    def make_from_int(cls, int arg):
        cdef NestedClassWrapper o = cls.__new__(cls)
        o.nc = new MyFirstClass.NestedClass(arg)
        return o

    # and the same pattern for the int and string versions

cdef class NestedClassWrapper2:
    cdef MyFirstClass.NestedClass* nc
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.nc

    def __cinit__(self, arg):
        if isinstance(arg, int):
            # cast to a C int
            self.nc = new MyFirstClass.NestedClass(<int>arg)
        elif isinstance(arg, float):
            self.nc = new MyFirstClass.NestedClass(<double>arg)
        elif isinstance(arg, bytes):
            self.nc = new MyFirstClass.NestedClass(<std_string>arg)
        else:
            raise TypeError
```

Other variations on the theme might also exist. For example a fused type as an argument to `__cinit__`, or using `try: ... except` to test the type conversions rather than `isinstance`. But most solutions will look something like one of these two approaches.

---

`cppclass` should be recognised providing you name the file `.pyx`. It may not be highlighted by your editor though.

Comment: Thanks so much, this makes more sense